# Hash Function to create unique hash for 70 million Strings with return type long

Tags: encryption, hash, hash-function

I want to create a hash function that converts 70 million unique string to a hash key which is long .

I have explored possible options and most of them return a combination of string and long .

Is there a hash functions that can do it .

Comment: Why can't you just take the first 8 bytes of a common hash function like SHA-256?

Comment: @Luke Joshua Park because in that case there's a chance that there may be  same first  8 bytes hash for more than one string and there are alphabets in the hash key . I only want long

Comment: You haven't specified a language. Type "long" doesn't mean anything without a specific language. Hash functions return an answer of a fixed number of bits. Thus for example the first 8 bytes of SHA256 can form a 64-bit long in Java, and with 70M inputs the probability of any collisions is only about one in a four thousand. If it happens, pick another hash function.

Comment: A long is 8 bytes in many languages. What is the byte size of a long in your language? Collisions are a potential issue regardless. What do you mean by "alphabets in the hash key"?

Comment: If your universe of strings is fixed and there only 70 million of them, here's a brute force mechanism.  Since you are generating a 64-bit number for each string then you can start off with a good 32-bit hash function.  If you are lucky, then there won't be too many collisions.  But, for each collision, you need to save the duplicate 32-bit ids, and index each one of them.  So, for example you have two strings: `abc` and `def` that both hash to the 32-bit ID 1. Save that `abc` has index 0, and `def` has index 1. The unique hash for `abc` is 0x0000000100000000 and `def` is 0x0000000100000001.